# HTML CSS flexible growing lists

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a react components, which renders 2 lists. Both lists can dynamically get bigger or smaller.
I've got 100% space vertically. If both lists are big, than every list should take 50% height.
If any list isn't big enough to take the whole 50% height space, than the other one should grow.

I can't find a working solution so far. I think flex-grow and shrink is a good way to do it, but it doesnt work for me.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.list_1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.list_2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="list_1">
    <li>Item 1a</li>
    <li>Item 1b</li>
    <li>Item 1c</li>
  </div>
  <div classs="list_2">
    <li>Item 2a</li>
    <li>Item 2b</li>
    <li>Item 2c</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried so many thinks from documentations but nothing works..

Comment: * than the other one should grow* It is not so clear what exactly do you want? Please be clear with sufficient data.

Comment: For this to work you would need to assign a height to the overall container. Otherwise you are trying to divide an unknown number into 50%.

Comment: @decpk sorry, I mean if maybe the first list isn't big enough and can't reach the 50% max-height, then the other list should take the space. So maybe the first list is 30%, then the other list should take 70% height. But only, if the second list is big enough for it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Oopps. the .container also have height: 100vh , sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the following snippet, I have given `flex: 1` to both `.list-1` and `.list-2`.

So when the second list grow, the first one shrinked.

If both has equal items, both will have 50% width also.

Please check and try updating your code with this solution.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   height: 300px;
}
.list_1, .list_2 {
   flex: 1;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="list_1">
      <ul>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
          <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="list_2">
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this solution, the list_1 does not shrink and list 2 does not grow, when list_1 got 1 item in it and list_2 got 30 items in it. both are still at 50% height.

Comment: Currently in the snippet, list one got 3 items and list 2 has 10 items. But list 2 has more height, and list 1 has lesser hight, right ? If both has 3 items per se, both will have 50% height also. Right ?

Comment: Yeah thats right, your snippet is working. Im currently trying to check why my example isn't working like that

Comment: Ok. Check and let me know

Comment: It worked! The parents had some overriding CSS attributes